# Android Back Stack in fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi i an Question on BackStack,
[image]

in screen it should not back back from 3 to 2 screen on clicking back button on Android phone.

but inside the 3 screen , first it will show home screen , then book and atlast xyz

when e clik back in 3 screen it came to from xyz to books screen then to home screen finaly it should not go back to 2 screen .

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()add(R.id.frame_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Username and password is Activity ,

3-screen is FragmentActivty

Comment: are username, password fragments or activities?

Comment: on onBackPressed() we can get counter of BackStack using getBackStackEntryCount(). on 0th position we can stop the fragment to move to other activity...

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with password activity.. you can simply add `finish()` statement before `startActivity(Home)` in this case it will be removed from the BackStack and when pressing back it will exit you from the application

so it should be something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ..homeActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

same goes for username activity if you don't want to get back to it

Comment: it not working,  it should not exit we have to logout form App

Comment: If this is the case, then in the onBackPressMethod of your FragmentActivity check if the back stack is null then call your LogoutFragment.

Comment: if i use backstack it working for 3 screen , but i want i should go from 3 to 2 screen.

Comment: so you want to got to screen 2 after logout?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to retain the activities or fragment activities in backstack use `noHistory` in activity tag of your menifest.

```
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: i fragments in want backstack , but in fragment activity i click back it should'n go to password screen..

Comment: then application should exit?

Comment: it should not exit , we have to logout the screen

Comment: Override the onBackPressed Method

Comment: if I use this at my 3 screes it works, bur back stack is not working